# Triangles, sine and cosine problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Hi everyone I tried solving this countless times but I always get the wrong answer! what I did first is 600/tan(46) - 600/tan(40) and that sounded reasonable to find the answer! but I keep getting it wrong :( there was a similar question but I got it right.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: the two distances  should be added; not subtracted.

Comment: That actually worked, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. what do you mean actually? were you expecting not to work?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$$\tan(40^\circ)=\frac{600}{x}$$

$$\tan(46^\circ)=\frac{600}{y}$$

So,
$$\text{Distance} = x+y=\frac{600}{\tan(40^\circ)}+\frac{600}{\tan(46^\circ)}=600\left(\frac{1}{\tan(40^\circ)}+\frac{1}{\tan(46^\circ)}\right)$$